# Mount fails with "no such device"

Tags: mount, smb, cifs

I have a network share on a fritz box router.
I was able to mount it from a raspberry with

**/etc/fstab**

```
//FRITZ-NAS/myBox/SanDisk-Cruzer /mnt/fritz_box cifs defaults,noauto,nofail,credentials=/root/fritzCreds 0 0
```

But after replacing the fritz box (and restoring the configuration) I'm getting

> Retrying with upper case share name
>   mount error(6): No such device or address

But other devices in my network are still able to access the share.
Even this works

```
smbclient -N "//FRITZ-NAS/myBox" -A fritzCreds  -c ls

Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.37]
  .                                  DR        0  Sat Jul 22 17:35:45 2017
  SanDisk-Cruzer                      D        0  Sat Jul 22 17:35:45 2017
```

The mounting itself seems to connect the router and also uses the credentials, but then it fails.

```
mount.cifs -vvv //FRITZ-NAS/myBox /mnt/fritz_box -o"credentials=/root/fritzCreds"

domain=WORKGROUP  
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.178.1,unc=\\FRITZ-NAS\myBox,user=myUser,,domain=WORKGROUP,pass=********  
Retrying with upper case share name  
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.178.1,unc=\\FRITZ-NAS\MYBOX,user=myUser,,domain=WORKGROUP,pass=********  
mount error(6): No such device or address  
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Without the credentials I get

```
mount.cifs -vvv //FRITZ-NAS/myBox /mnt/fritz_box

Password for root@//FRITZ-NAS/myBox
```

Whats going wrong here? How to repair it?